# Missing second occurrence of verb

Tags: ellipsis

> She is intelligent but her sisters are dull.
>    She is intelligent but her sisters dull.

Both sentences are correct. But the second sentence is missing "is" before dull. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

> She is intelligent but her sisters dull.

The missing word 'are' after 'sisters' is an example of 'ellipsis', to be specific, 'gapping':

> a situation in which words are left out of a sentence but the sentence
>   can still be understood.

“I went to the mall on Monday, and she on Sunday.” (meaning “I went to the mall on Monday, and she **went to the mall** on Sunday.”)

There is a second, related meaning of 'ellipsis':

> three dots in a printed text that show where one or more words have
>   been intentionally left out.

"You went to the restaurant, and…?" (meaning "You went to the restaurant, and what happened?")

[Ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ellipsis)

[Literary devices: ellipsis](http://www.literarydevices.com/ellipsis/)

[Gapping](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gapping)

Comment: [...] but her sisters, dull.

Comment: It's actually called 'gapping', or in full  'gapped coordination'.

Comment: Note that if the sentence were spoken, it would sound like: **She is intelligent but her sister's dull**.

Comment: If I were speaking, I'd use a pause and intonation to hopefully steer the listener away from an unintended interpretation.

Comment: @Billj, gapping is a type of ellipsis.

Comment: 'Gapping' has a specific meaning, i.e. it is (virtually) restricted to coordinative constructions where the gap is understood by reference to the first coordinate, which is why we use it instead of 'ellipsis'.

Comment: The specific meaning is that gapping is an ellipsis in which a verb is removed in one, or more, of a series of coordinations.

Comment: I'm not trying to nit-pick here, but why didn't you use the term 'gapping' in your answer, since this is the broadly accepted term for such constructions?

Comment: I was being general.